# Scalable Architecture Decision Record (ADR) tool

Tags: static-site-generator

There are many tools supporting the ADR processes, although majority is very simple ([madr](https://adr.github.io/madr/)), dead ([log4brains](https://github.com/thomvaill/log4brains)), or do not scale well with the amount (100s) and age of the records (the entire product lifecycle - features come and go).

Basically it's a bunch of markdown files rendered to a searchable webpage.

The basic requirements are:

- rendering of record timeline
- record search (by tags, title, etc.)
- filtering of records by state (irrelevant, in design, etc.)

It still seems developing a custom Hugo/Jekyll theme is the way to go...